# VBA conditional formatting based on contents of merged cells

Tags: vba, merge, excel-2003, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet set up like this:

```
1   Basic Rota  09:00   13:00
2   Absence           S
```

If you imagine the column labels start above 'Basic Rota' as A, B and C.  The Absence cell (B2:C2) is a merged cell which can contain either 'H','S','T','SC' or it can be empty. Based on the contents of that cell, B1 and C1 should change colour. I have a bit of VBA which does the job.

```
Option Compare Text 'A=a, B=b, ... Z=z
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Selection As Range)

        Select Case Target.Value

    Case "S"

        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 53
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 53
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 53
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 53

    Case "H"

        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 50
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 50

    Case "T"

        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 44
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 44

    Case "SC"

        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 42
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 42

    Case Else

        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'No Fill
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

End Select

End Sub
```

However, if the contents of the merged cell (B2:C2) are deleted, I receive an error (Run-time error '13': Type Mistmatch) on the line 'Case "S"
'. I can get around it with an 'On Error GoTo' line, but it means that the cell that has been conditionally formatted doesn't get returned to 'no fill'. This isn't an issue if it's done on cells that aren't merged, so it could be that I need to stop using merged cells all together - however, for user friendliness it'd be nice to keep it (rather than making the user input 'H' twice in B2 and C2 for example).  For reference, this is for Excel 2003.  I should add that the macro is added to a worksheet by viewing the code for that worksheet and is based on worksheet_change.

If anyone could assist on this it'd be much appreciated!

Edit:  Answer below based on @Philip A Barnes' answer.

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


  Select Case Target.Columns(1).Value

  Case Empty

    Target.Columns(1).MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'No Fill
    Target.Columns(1).MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

Case "S"

    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 53
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 53
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 53
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 53

Case "H"

    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 50
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 50

Case "T"

    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 44
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 44

Case "SC"

    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 42
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 42

Case Else

    Target.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'No Fill
    Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: Why don't you run VBA to find the merged cells, either skip them, or reset colorIndex to have no colour...

Comment: @assylias - the error points to the 'Case "S"' in the macro. Thanks.@bonCodigo - The input happens in the merged cell so I don't think I'd want to skip them.  I think the caseelse should work (and does work on a non merged cell) so I'm not sure how to do what you suggest.  Thanks.

Comment: What I said doesn't merely say to skip the merged cell. It is possible to colour even merge cells. My suggestion was to do anything when you encounter a merged cell. e.g. you could check if the mergecell has any data. If it doesn't then you do not have to validate that. Can you edit your post by uploading a screen shot of your spreadhseet data plus how you want it to look after formatting is applied? It will make this easier.

Comment: @bonCodigo - thanks, that makes a bit more sense.  I can't post a screenshot at the moment but I will try to do so later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because when you have no data in the cell the Target reference returns "Empty". You need to extend your case statement to check for this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Select Case Target.Columns(1).Value

    Case Empty

        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'No Fill
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    Case "S"

        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 53
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 53
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 53
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 53

    Case "H"

        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 50
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 50

    Case "T"

        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 44
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 44

    Case "SC"

        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = 42
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Font.ColorIndex = 42

    Case Else

        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'No Fill
        Target.MergeArea.Offset(-1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

End Select

End Sub
```

Make sure it is the first check you do. Also I would suggest looking into Excels built in Conditional Formatting which you can manipulate using VBA.

Comment: Thanks, but if I add that to the beginning of my case statement, it still returns the same error starting at 'Case Empty'.  For this particular spreadsheet I need more than 3 conditional formats, which isn't allowed in Excel 2003 as far as I know.

Comment: see my above edit with full code, I receive no errors. How are you triggering the event? ALso Excel 2003 has a 3 limit cap, if you are using 2007 there is no such cap.

Comment: Thanks, oddly if I hit the 'delete' key, I receive the error.  If I select the contents of the cell and delete them via the formula bar, no error occurs!  Unfortunately we haven't updated to 2007 and won't for a while.

Comment: it was an edge case for merged cells. See my above edit, notably the Select Case Target.Columns(1).Value

Comment: Thanks, this is working after a slight tweak (see my answer above).  Many thanks!