# Using VBA on merged cells for Conditional formating

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I set some rules in VBA to conditionaly formating some cells of a Range.
Here is a sample of my code :

```
Private Sub FormatRange()
Dim Rng01, Rng02 As Range, 
listSep As String
Set Rng01 = Range("A14:O28")

listSep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)

Set Rng02 = Intersect(Rng01, Rng01.Parent.Range("H:K"))
Rng02.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, formula1:="=IsAlphaNumeric(" & Rng01.Cells(1,8).Address(0,1) & ")"
Rng02.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
End Sub
```

The cells H from K are merged together.
if I'm using the Conditional formating option the merged cells with a non alphanumeric caractére turn red, as expected.

But I want to use VBA, and according to this preview post :
[VBA conditional formatting based on contents of merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512635/vba-conditional-formatting-based-on-contents-of-merged-cells)
I can't get the value using : Rng01.Cells(1,8).Address(0,1) because Cells(1,8) only target the column "H" and not "H/I/J/K"

Any solutions ?

Comment: I am afraid, I cannot understand your question... Firstly, I cannot see anything to clarify your question looking to the linked thread. Secondly, what do you try accomplishing? Do you want formatting only "H:K" columns? If so, why involving `Rng01.Cells(1,8).Address(0,1)`? IF not, you try applying everything to `Rng02`. Then, it is mandatory to delete the previous `FormatConditions`. Otherwise, a mixed between the former and the last conditions will not bring something good. And finally, where from did you take `IsAlphaNumeric` formula? What Excel version do you use?

Comment: Still alive? Don't you have anything to say...?

Comment: @FaneDuru Can you be less impatient please ?

Comment: "A mixed between the former and the last conditions will not bring something good" what do you mean by that ? I can't add more rules ?

Comment: Without deletion of the previous formatCongitions, `Rng02.FormatConditions.Add` simple adds  a new condition! 1, 2, 3 ... n. And you modify the formula of `FormatConditions(1)`, which was wrong when you firstly tried it. But I would suggest you to test the code I posted and you will maybe understand better where the problem was, or explain where I assumed is wrong. I already starting to feel I am wasting my time, no offence. I lost my enthusiasm...

Comment: You choose to wast your time with me ... thanks for your help, not for your attitude.

Comment: I've only chosen to help you! But it is, at least, strange to be **me** the most interested one to solve your problem and you being offended when pushed to clarify my questions.  I needed to go out and wanted to have the questions clarified, in order to supply an answer not only based on my assumptions, which proved to really be a waste of time. No need to answer anything this time...

Answer (score 1):

If my assumptions are correct, this might work for you:

```
Private Sub FormatRange()
    Dim Rng01 As Range, Rng02 As Range, listSep As String
    Set Rng01 = Range("A14:O28")
    
    listSep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
    
    Set Rng02 = Intersect(Rng01, Rng01.Parent.Range("H:K"))
    Dim fc As FormatCondition
    Set fc = Rng02.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=IsAlphaNumeric(" & Rng02.Cells(1, 1).MergeArea.Address(0, 1) & ")")
    fc.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Erik I'm making some test with this "MergeArea" feature. I didn't know it's existing. I let you know

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not clarify my comment question, please try the next way. It assumes that you want conditional formatting **all `Rng01` range** based on alpha numeric values in merged cells ("H:K"). All cells to have a red `Interior` in such a case. If the code uses `Rng01.Cells(1,8).Address(0,1)` it is enough, because a merged cells group exposed only its first cell:

```
Private Sub FormatRangeAlpha()
 Dim Rng01 As Range, Rng02 As Range, listSep As String
 Set Rng01 = Range("A14:O28")

 listSep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)

 Set Rng02 = Intersect(Rng01, Rng01.Parent.Range("H:K"))
 With Rng01
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, formula1:="=NOT(ISNUMBER(" & .cells(1, 8).Address(0, 1) & "))"
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reasons It's working now without editing the code ...
The only things I did was to unmerge my cells H:K and then merge them again.
Now it's working for each row as expected.